# How to filter data with two conditions for each of the two observation?

Tags: r

So I wish to find the income difference between couples who share the same occupation and those who do not. I now have individual-level data with occupation and household code for the analysis.

Here is my data
[image]

[image]
The data code is

```
structure(list(YEAR = structure(c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L), 
    SAMPLE = structure(c(202101L, 202101L, 202101L, 202101L, 
    202101L, 202101L), 
    CBSERIAL = structure(c(2021010000026, 2021010000031, 2021010000063, 
    2021010000067, 2021010000100, 2021010000227), label = "Original Census Bureau household serial number", 
    HHWT = structure(c(13, 51, 17, 61, 15, 46), label = "Household weight", 
    CLUSTER = structure(c(2021000000011, 2021000000021, 2021000000031, 
    2021000000041, 2021000000051, 2021000000061), label = "Household cluster for variance estimation", 
    STRATA = structure(c(80001, 80001, 120001, 170001, 50001, 
    160001), label = "Household strata for variance estimation", 
    GQ = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), labels = structure(0:6, names = c("Vacant unit", 
    "Households under 1970 definition", "Additional households under 1990 definition", 
    "Group quarters--Institutions", "Other group quarters", "Additional households under 2000 definition", 
    "Fragment")), label = "Group quarters status",   
 US2021A_DIVISION = structure(c("6", 
    "6", "6", "6", "6", "6"), labels = c(`New England (Northeast region)` = "1", 
    `Middle Atlantic (Northeast region)` = "2", `East North Central (Midwest region)` = "3", 
    `West North Central (Midwest region)` = "4", `South Atlantic (South region)` = "5", 
    `East South Central (South region)` = "6", `West South Central (South Region)` = "7", 
    `Mountain (West region)` = "8", `Pacific (West region)` = "9"
    ), label = "Division code based on 2010 Census definitions", var_desc = "", 
 US2021A_PUMA = structure(c("00800", 
    "00800", "01200", "01700", "00500", "01600"), label = "Public use microdata area code (PUMA) based on 2010 Census definition (areas with population of 100,000 or more, use with ST for unique code)", 

PERNUM = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), label = "Person number in sample unit", 
    PERWT = structure(c(13, 51, 17, 61, 15, 46), label = "Person weight", 
    US2021A_AGEP = structure(c("85", "67", "74", "16", "83", 
    "19"), 
 US2021A_MAR = structure(c("1", 
    "2", "2", "5", "3", "5"), 
    
    US2021A_PINCP = structure(c("0015000", "0004800", "0036000", 
    "0000000", "0007200", "0008000"), label = "Total person's income (signed, use ADJINC to adjust to constant dollars)", var_desc = ""), 
    US2021A_SOCP = structure(c("BBBBBB", "BBBBBB", "BBBBBB", 
    "BBBBBB", "BBBBBB", "412031"), 
 PERWT_SP = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), label = "Person weight [of Spouse's location in household]", 
    US2021A_AGEP_SP = structure(c("", "", "", "", "", ""),  label = "Age [of Spouse's location in household]", 
US2021A_SEX_SP = structure(c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), labels = c(Male = "1", Female = "2"), label = "Sex [of Spouse's location in household]", 

  US2021A_ESR_SP = structure(c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), labels = c(`Civilian employed, at work` = "1", 
    `Civilian employed, with a job but not at work` = "2", Unemployed = "3", 
    `Armed forces, at work` = "4", `Armed forces, with a job but not at work` = "5", 
    `Not in labor force` = "6", `N/A (less than 16 years old)` = "B"
    ), 
US2021A_PERNP_SP = structure(c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), label = "Total person's earnings (use ADJINC to adjust to constant dollars) [of Spouse's location in household]", var_desc = ""), 
    US2021A_PINCP_SP = structure(c("", "", "", "", "", ""), label = "Total person's income (signed, use ADJINC to adjust to constant dollars) [of Spouse's location in household]", var_desc = ""), 
    US2021A_SOCP_SP = structure(c("", "", "", "", "", ""), label = "Standard Occupational Classification (SOC) codes for 2018 and later based on 2018 SOC codes [of Spouse's location in household]", 
 class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "character"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

but I don't know how to filter out the data so that I can have every two person grouped in one CBSERIAL(household) variable, while also having the same US2021A_SOCP variable

My thought is to use a for loop for this, to iterate between every two elements. But I all I can find is the setequal function, which is not exactly what I need.

Comment: SO is for specific code questions, not for ideation. Please provide a minimum, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for the tips! It is my first time asking questions on Stack Overflow. I have updated the question so that it might be clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could provide the data using `dput(head(mydf))`, but roughly the following should work:

```
library(dplyr)

mydf |>
  filter(US2021A_SOCP != "BBBBBB", PERWT_SP != "NA", US2021A_AGEP %in% (25:45), US2021A_MAR == "1") |>
  # For each household...
  group_by(CBSERIAL) |> 
  # ... Determine how many unique categories appear for US2021A_SOCP and keep only those whose length is 1
  filter(length(unique(US2021A_SOCP)) == 1) |>
  # Remove the group_by household requirement
  ungroup() |>
  arrange(US2021A_SOCP, CBSERIAL)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I don't know how I can send the code since it is very large. Could you tell me how to take a sample of it?
Also, I had a function for filtering the data already, 'data %>% filter(US2021A_SOCP != "BBBBBB", PERWT_SP != "NA", US2021A_AGEP %in% (25:45), US2021A_MAR == "1",)'

Comment: Using `dput(head())` will only return the first 6 rows of the data.  My code can follow the filters you already have in place.

Comment: I have presented some data in the question hopefully it is understandable.
In addition, I have already written a line of code to filter the data `data %>% filter(US2021A_SOCP != "BBBBBB", PERWT_SP != "NA", US2021A_AGEP %in% (25:45), US2021A_MAR == "1",)` How can I add your code onto the one already existed?

Comment: I added your filter line to my answer above.

Comment: It now does look like it has couples with the same occupation grouped together, however, I cannot easily see them as they are hidden inside other observations. Is there any function you recommend for me to use to clean the data so that I can see it for certain SOCP accordingly?

Comment: I've added a line to sort by occupation and household.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! It works now! However, I see that for the SOCP variable, only the variables containing  111021 are shown. I tried to switch the position of `filter` and `group` function around to no avail.  Could you tell me the mechanism behind the idea of the function so I can try it on my own?

Comment: Perhaps it's the only instance where this is true. I've added in the answer a line detailing the logic.